# Vue component render function: print unescaped html entity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I make Vue 2 render my component without escaping the HTML entity and printing it as normal text? If it were a tag, I'd nest another `createElement`, but this is not the case.

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('div', '&nbsp;')
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: [
    'my-component'
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define DOM properties and HTML attributes in the second argument of `createElement` function.

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth

Solution:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('div', {
        domProps: {
          innerHTML: '&nbsp;'
        }
    })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: [
    'my-component'
  ]
})

console.log(document.getElementById('app').firstChild.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

**Update after comment:**

you can populate your component with children like this:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('div', 
    [
      createElement('p', 'top tag'),
      createElement('div', {
        domProps: {
            innerHTML: 'A&nbsp;B'
          }
      }),
      createElement('p', 'bottom tag'),
    ]
    )
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: [
    'my-component'
  ]
})

console.log(document.getElementById('app').firstChild.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, excellent, that does the trick. But what if there are other children inside the same element? The `innerHTML` doesn't play nice with other elements...